# hide a table td using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code how can i hide the id column of the table.

```
var joblist = "";
joblist = joblist + "<table ><tr><th >Select</th><th id='td_1'>ID</th><th >Name</th><th >Names</th><th>OS</th><th >Server</th></tr>";

var tabString = '<tr ><td > ' + '<input type="radio" name="joblist" onclick="myfunc(this);"  id= ' + value.jobid + 'value=' + value.jobid + '> </td><td id="td_1" >' + value._id + '</td><td >' + value.names + '</td><td a>' + value.os +  '</td><td >' + value.server + '</td></tr>';

joblist = joblist + tabString;
```

I tried

```
$("#td_1").hide()
```

But it is not working.Any other solutions?

Comment: on what event you want to hide `$("#td_1")` ?

Comment: By "not working", what does it actually do? Are you wanting to hide the entire second column of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if there is multiple td then don't use same id, in this case add some other post or pre. And use as

```
 $('[id^="td_1"]').hide();//for post
 $('[id$="td_1"]').hide();//pre
```

Try this

```
 $('[id="td_1"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `ID` must be `unique`. you have declared same ID for `TH` and `TD`

```
$("#your_td_id").hide();
```

if you more than one `TD` then use `class` instead of `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you cannot match multiple elements based purely on an ID; they must be unique across the entire document. I suspect that what you are seeing is the 'ID' heading disappearing from the top of your table, but the values remaining visible later on in the table.

Other answers have mentioned switching to a class; there is another alternative available, using the `nth-child` pseudo-selector:

```
    $("table tr > *:nth-child(2)").hide();
```

This will hide the 2nd element immediately under `tr`, as `*` matches both the `TH` and the `TD`. If you never want it visible, then better solutions include CSS:

```
    table tr > *:nth-child(2) { display: none; }
```

or simply rendering it into an `<input type='hidden' />` instead and including it in one of your existing cells (e.g. alongside the radio button).

Note that you have a few additional errors in your HTML, including:

```
    <td a>' + value.os +
```

that you may want to investigate at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Before hiding an element you must assign it to DOM. If you want to hide multiple elements you must use `class` attribute instead of `id`

```
var joblist = "";
joblist = joblist + "<table ><tr><th >Select</th><th class='td_1'>ID</th>" +
                    "<th >Name</th><th >Names</th><th>OS</th><th >Server</th></tr>";

var tabString = '<tr ><td > ' + '<input type="radio" name="joblist" 
               onclick="myfunc(this);"  id= ' + value.jobid + 'value=' + 
               value.jobid + '> </td><td class="td_1" >' + value._id +
              '</td><td >'+ value.names + '</td><td a>' + value.os +  
              '</td><td >' +  value.server + '</td></tr>';

joblist = joblist + tabString;

$('#myElement').append(joblist);
$('.td_1').hide();
```